# Keras fit_generator() doesn't train properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am trying to create an image classifier using Keras and TensorFlow 2.0.0 backend.

I'm training this model on my local machine on a custom dataset containing a total of 17~ thousand images. The images vary in size and are located in three different folders (training, validation, and test), each containing two subfolders (one for each class).
I tried an architecture similar to VGG16, which yielded more than decent results on this dataset in the past. Note, there is a minor class imbalance in the data (52:48)

When I call `fit_generator()`, the model doesn't train well; although the training loss lowers slightly throughout the first epoch, it does not change much afterward. Using this architecture with higher regulation, I achieved 85% accuracy after 55~ epochs in the past.

Imports and hyperparameters

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import backend as k
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Input, UpSampling2D
from keras.models import Sequential, Model, load_model
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

TRAIN_PATH = 'data/train/'
VALID_PATH = 'data/validation/'
TEST_PATH = 'data/test/'
TARGET_SIZE = (256, 256)
RESCALE = 1.0 / 255
COLOR_MODE = 'grayscale'
EPOCHS = 2
BATCH_SIZE = 16
CLASSES = ['Damselflies', 'Dragonflies']
CLASS_MODE = 'categorical'
CHECKPOINT = "checkpoints/weights.hdf5"
```

Model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(256, 256, 1), padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(516, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

In the past, I created a custom pipeline to reshape, grayscale, flip, and normalize the images; then, I trained the model using my CPU on batches of processed images.

I tried repeating the process using ImageDataGenerator, flow_from_directory, and GPU support.

```
# randomly flip images, and scale pixel values
trainGenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=RESCALE, 
                                    horizontal_flip=True,  
                                    vertical_flip=True)

# only scale the pixel values validation images
validatioinGenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=RESCALE)

# only scale the pixel values test images
testGenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=RESCALE)

# instanciate train flow
trainFlow = trainGenerator.flow_from_directory(
    TRAIN_PATH,
    target_size = TARGET_SIZE,
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    classes = CLASSES,
    color_mode = COLOR_MODE,
    class_mode = CLASS_MODE,
    shuffle=True
) 

# instanciate validation flow
validationFlow = validatioinGenerator.flow_from_directory(
    VALID_PATH,
    target_size = TARGET_SIZE,
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    classes = CLASSES,
    color_mode = COLOR_MODE,
    class_mode= CLASS_MODE,
    shuffle=True
)
```

Then, fitting the model using fit_generator.

```
checkpoints = ModelCheckpoint(CHECKPOINT, monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')

with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
    model.fit_generator(
        trainFlow,
        validation_data=validationFlow, 
        callbacks=[checkpoints],
        epochs=EPOCHS
    )
```

I tried training it for 40 epochs.
The classifier achieves 52% after the first epoch and does not improve as time goes by.

Testing the classifier

```
testFlow = testGenerator.flow_from_directory(
    TEST_PATH,
    target_size = TARGET_SIZE,
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    classes = CLASSES,
    color_mode = COLOR_MODE,
    class_mode= CLASS_MODE,
)

ans = model.predict_generator(testFlow)
```

When I look at the predictions, the model predicts all the test images as the majority class with the same confidence `[0.48498476, 0.51501524]`.

> Have I made sure the data is correct?

Yes. I tested whether the generators yield processed images and their corresponding labels correctly.

> Have I tried changing the loss function, activation function, and optimizer?

Yes. I tried changing the class mode to binary, the loss to binary_crossentropy, and changing the last layer to produce a single output with sigmoid activation. No, I did not change the optimizer. However, I did try to increase the learning rate.

> Have I tried changing the model's architecture?

Yes. I tried increasing and decreasing model complexity.
Both more layers with less regularization and fewer layers with more regularization produced similar results.

> Are the layers trainable?

Yes.

> Is the GPU support implemented correctly?

I hope so.

`print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))`

Num GPUs Available:  1

```
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a') 
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b') 
c = tf.matmul(a, b)

config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True) 
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True 
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
print(sess)
```

*Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 with Max-Q Design, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0, compute capability: 6.1*

*<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x000001F9443E2CC0>*

> Have I tried transfer learning?

Not yet.

I found a similar unanswered question from 2017 [keras-doesnt-train-using-fit-generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44245813/keras-doesnt-train-using-fit-generator).

Thoughts?

Comment: You should set shuffle to False for the validation dataset.

Comment: Hey, since the validation is not used to update the weights, only to inform us how the model is doing, does it matter?

Does it affect the model's training process? @M.Innat

Comment: I could not find fit_generator() for tf.keras 2.11 on the official page: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model . There is only fit() and train_on_batch().

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your model. I copied your code and ran it on a data set I have used before (which gets high accuracy) and got results similar to yours. I then substituted  the simple model below

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(256 , 256,1)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu' ),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(128, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(.3),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(.3),
    Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The model trained properly. By the way model.fit_generator is depreciated. You can now just use model.fit which can now handle generators. I then took your model and removed all the dropout layers except for the last one and your model trained properly. Code is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(256, 256, 1), padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(516, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Thanks @Gerry P

I tried applying your suggestion and removing the Dropout layers.
Unfortunately, it did not work for me.

`Epoch 1/20 loss: 0.6956 - accuracy: 0.5163 - val_loss: 0.6519 - val_accuracy: 0.5235
Epoch 2/20 loss: 0.6924 - accuracy: 0.5207 - val_loss: 0.6509 - val_accuracy: 0.5235
Epoch 3/20 loss: 0.6925 - accuracy: 0.5207 - val_loss: 0.6568 - val_accuracy: 0.5235
Epoch 4/20 loss: 0.6924 - accuracy: 0.5207 - val_loss: 0.6589 - val_accuracy: 0.5235`

Also same predictions ```[0.4853577, 0.5146423]```

Comment: strange worked fine for me.  Did you try the model I provided? I copied all your code with the exception of the line with tf.device('/GPU:0'):, so only thing I can think of is the nature of your data. If you are on Kaggle try downloading this dataset at https://www.kaggle.com/gpiosenka/beauty-detection-data-set and see if the model trains correctly on it

Comment: Thank you! I found the problem.
removing  the import `from keras import backend as k`
resolved the issue

Comment: great sorry I didn't find it

Answer (score 0):

@Gerry P,

By accident, I found what's causing the error.
Removing `from Keras import backend as k` resolved the model's inability to learn.

That's not all. I also identified that the model you defined, not calling ModelCheckpoint, and not customizing class names affected the fitting process.

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(256 , 256, 1)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu' ),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(128, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(.3),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(.3),
    Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])
```

I commented that import to try and resolve an error that occurred when I copy-pasted your sequential model. Then, I forgot to uncomment it when I tested it beautiful or average dataset. I achieved over 80% accuracy after the third epoch. Then, I reverted the changes and tried it on my dataset, and it failed again.
As a bonus, not importing Keras's backend decreased the time it takes to train the model!

Lately, I had to re-install Keras and TensorFlow because they couldn't detect my GPU anymore. I probably made a mistake and installed an incompatible version of Keras.

```
CUDA==10.0
tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0
keras==2.3.1
```

Note, it's still not a 100% solution, and the problems arise every so often.

EDIT:

Whenever it doesn't work, simplify the model.
Changed batch size and stopped learning? Simplify the model.
Augmented the images further and stopped learning? Simplify the model.